# A couple menu choices coming back incorrect

Tags: c#, menu, user-input

Rough draft of the entire program, but I am trying to get my menu working properly and am running into an issue that I cannot stump. When testing the application for the customer menu, 1-4 returns correctly but 5 is not.  I would like 5 to just return to the main menu, but it is returning my error checking output.  The same issue is in the manager menu also, where 1-4 returns correctly but 5 and 6 do not.  They both direct me to my error checking output also.  How could I go about altering my code to make each of my submenu functions work correctly?

```
        MainMenu();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    static void MainMenu()
    {
        int userChoice = MainMenuChoice(); // Reading in the userChoice with the MenuChoice method

        if (userChoice == 3) // if user enters 3, the program ends
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you, Goodbye!");
        }

        while (userChoice != 3)
        {
            if (userChoice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the customer menu!\n"); // The customer menu is brought up if user enters 1
                CustomerMenu();
            }
            if (userChoice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the manager menu!\n"); // The manager menu is brought up if user enters 2
                ManagerMenu();
            }
            userChoice = MainMenuChoice(); // program ends
            if (userChoice == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you for visiting VideoMart at University Boulevard, Goodbye!");

            }
        }

    }
    static int MainMenuChoice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"); // introducing the user with the menu 
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to VideoMart at University Boulevard!  \nAt VideoMart you are able to rent a variety of movies from many genres such as action, family, horror, etc!");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 if you are a customer");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 2 if you are a manager");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 3 to Exit");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        while (!(choice == "1" || choice == "2" || choice == "3")) // error checking
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 if you are a customer");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 if you are a manager");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 3 to Exit");

            choice = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return int.Parse(choice);
    }


 static void CustomerMenu() {

        int customerChoice = CustomerMenuChoice(); // Reading in the customerChoice into the CustomerMenuChoice method

        if (customerChoice == 5) // if user enters 5, the user is returned to the main menu
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning to main menu, thank you.");
        }

        while (customerChoice != 5)
        {
            if (customerChoice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This shows movies available.\n"); // this option gives the user the opportunity to view all movies available to rent
                 //MoviesAvailable();
            }
            if (customerChoice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is to rent a movie.\n"); // this option gives the user the opportunity to rent a movie, with email address
                //RentMovie();
            }
            if (customerChoice == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is to show my rented movies.\n"); // this option gives the user the opportunity to view movies a user currently has rented, with email address
                //MyRentedMovie();
            }
            if (customerChoice == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is to return a movie.\n"); // this option gives the user the opportunity to return a movie rented
                //ReturnMovie();
            }
            customerChoice = CustomerMenuChoice();
            if (customerChoice == 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Returning to main menu, thank you.");
            }
        }            
}
    static int CustomerMenuChoice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Below is a list of actions that can be performed by customers: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to view movies available to rent.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 2 to rent a movie.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 3 to view a list of movies you currently have rented.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 4 to return a movie rented.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 5 to return to menu.");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        string customerChoice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        while (!(customerChoice2 == "1" || customerChoice2 == "2" || customerChoice2 == "3" || customerChoice2 == "4") || customerChoice2 == "5") // error checking
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid option: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to view movies available to rent.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 2 to rent a movie.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 3 to view a list of movies you currently have rented.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 4 to return a movie rented.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 5 to return to menu.");

            customerChoice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return int.Parse(customerChoice2);
    }
 static void ManagerMenu() {

        int managerChoice = ManagerMenuChoice(); // Reading in the managerChoice into the ManagerMenuChoice method

        if (managerChoice == 6) // if user enters 6, the user is returned to the main menu
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning to main menu, thank you.");
        }

        while (managerChoice != 6)
        {
            if (managerChoice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is to add a movie to inventory.\n"); // this option gives the manager the ability to add a movie to inventory
                 //AddMovie();
            }
            if (managerChoice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is to remove a movie from inventory.\n"); // this option gives the manager the ability to remove a movie from inventory
                //RemoveMovie();
            }
            if (managerChoice == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is to edit a movie from inventory.\n"); // this option gives the manager the ability to edit a movie to inventory
                //EditMovie();
            }
            if (managerChoice == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is to process a btach transaction file.\n"); // this option gives the manager the ability to process a batch transaction file
                //BatchTransaction();
            }
            if (managerChoice == 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is to access the report menu.\n"); // this option gives the manager the ability to access the report menu
                 //ReportMenu();
            }
            managerChoice = ManagerMenuChoice();
            if (managerChoice == 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Returing to main menu, thank you.!"); // returns to main menu
            }
        }            
}
    static int ManagerMenuChoice()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Below is a list of actions that can be performed by managers: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to add a new movie to to the inventory.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 2 remove a movie from inventory.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 3 to edit a movie in inventory.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 4 to process a btach transaction file.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 5 to access the report menu.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 6 to return to the menu.");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        string managerChoice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        while (!(managerChoice2 == "1" || managerChoice2 == "2" || managerChoice2 == "3" || managerChoice2 == "4") || managerChoice2 == "5" || managerChoice2 == "6") // error checking
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid option: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to add a new movie to to the inventory.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 2 remove a movie from inventory.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 3 to edit a movie in inventory.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 4 to process a btach transaction file.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 5 to access the report menu.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 6 to return to the menu.");

            managerChoice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return int.Parse(managerChoice2);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Not an error, just not the correct answer I am looking for.  When the user enters the customer menu and enters 5, as you can see it in the code I would like it to say returning to menu, and return to the menu.  Instead, it says "Please enter a valid option: and displays all options".  Same issue persists with the manager menu, the inputs 5 and 6 do not return the value I am trying to achieve, but instead just "Please enter a valid option: and displays all options".  Just trying to pinpoint the error in my code so that I can get my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (!(customerChoice2 == "1" || customerChoice2 == "2" || customerChoice2 == "3" || customerChoice2 == "4") || customerChoice2 == "5")
```

If you look at this line you can see that the parenthesis doesn't include the "5".
So you are checking if the answer is something other than 1-4 OR it is 5.
Meaning 5 will always count as invalid.

*I would also like to give you a few tips that could make your code shorter and simpler, if you want to.*

First off, you could make the code always go into the loop and return only once the input is valid. This way you **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself (**DRY**).

```
static int CustomerMenuChoice()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Below is a list of actions that can be performed by customers: ");
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to view movies available to rent.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 2 to rent a movie.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 3 to view a list of movies you currently have rented.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 4 to return a movie rented.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress 5 to return to menu.");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        string customerChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        if (customerChoice == "1" || customerChoice == "2" || customerChoice == "3" || customerChoice == "4" || customerChoice == "5")
        {
            return int.Parse(customerChoice);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid option: ");
    } 
}
```

Secondly I recommend looking a bit at the [switch-case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) statement.

You could use it in several places of your code like so:

```
static void CustomerMenu()
{
    int customerChoice = 0;

    while (customerChoice != 5)
    {
        customerChoice = CustomerMenuChoice();

        switch (customerChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("This shows movies available.\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("This is to rent a movie.\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("This is to show my rented movies.\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("This is to show my rented movies.\n");
                break;
            case 5:
                Console.WriteLine("Returning to main menu, thank you.");
                break;
            default:
                // Option not in the list
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

One last thing, you might wanna look into using Console.ReadKey() instead of Console.ReadLine().
It will return without the user having to press enter and only takes one key at a time.
Personally I think it's perfect for these kinds of menus.